# Sequelize - this.get ()

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two file:

**server.js** for receive a request from the client:

```
var db = require("./db.js");
app.post("/users/login", function (req, res) {


    var body = _.pick(req.body, "email", "password");

    db.user.authenticate(body).then(function (data) {   //data is entire record and use "authenticate" function instance

        res.header("Auth", data.generateToken("authentication")).json(data);
    }, function (e) {
        res.status(401).send("Incorrect username or password! Please try again");
    })
```

**user.js**

```
...........
instanceMethods: {
            generateToken: function (type) {
                if (!_.isString(type)) {
                    return undefined;
                }

                try {
                    //"this" is refer of istance sequelize "user"
                    var stringData = JSON.stringify({ id: this.get("id"), type: type });

                    // encrypt json string "stringData" and we set a secret password for decrypt data
                    var encryptedData = crypto.AES.encrypt(stringData, "yyyy").toString();
                    var token = jwt.sign({
                        token: encryptedData
                    }, "xxxx");

                    return token;

                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    return undefined;
                } {

                }
            }
        }
```

When i call `data.generateToken` from server.js, i use `db.user` object that impprt all module from `user.js`. But how it know that with `this.get("id")` must take the id of `data` record? What is the connection between "this" and "data"? Important: "data" is a record of database that i received after have control the credentials send from user

Answer (score 0):

In your example `this` refers to the parent object that defines the instance method, which in this case is a Sequelize Instance, which is turn is an ES6 object. When you call `this.get()` you are calling the [`Instance.get(key, options)`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/instance/#getkey-options-objectany) function on the specific instance of the `Instance`.

It is getting the `User.id` and including that in the unique `stringData` value which is then used to generate the token.

Answer (score 0):

Ok then if i have into `user.js`:

```
var user = sequelize.define("user", {  
......

},

classMethods: {  //for create simple methods
            authenticate: function (body) { //pass body object from user.js ( api users/login ) into this class
                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { //built a promise for send back the reject or resolve result

                    if (typeof body.email == "string" && typeof body.password == "string") {

                        user.findOne({   //search a specific element into database
                            where: {
                                email: body.email   //where email into database is equals to email that you pass into JSON body
                            }
                        }).then(function (data) {   //return entire record from the database

                            //compareSync permit that compare the original password with password hashed + salt ( from the password_hash column from data table )
                            if (data && bcrypt.compareSync(body.password, data.get("password_hash"))) {
                                console.log("You are logged!");
                                return resolve(data);   
},

instanceMethods: {
            generateToken: function (type) {
                if (!_.isString(type)) {
                    return undefined;
                }

                try {
                    //"this" is refer of istance sequelize "user"
                    var stringData = JSON.stringify({ id: this.get("id"), type: type });
};
return user;
```

`this.get` it refers at user variable ? Then, into API of server.js, data is an instance of user variable so i can to access into `generateToken` method and pass `data` object replace of `this`?